# Como mudar valor dentro de uma linha gridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Pessoal estou trabalhando em um form PDV e estou com a seguinte dúvida.

No meu exemplo seria como modificar a quantidade do mesmo produto em uma única linha sem ter que repetir o produto toda vez que for adicionar no carrinho.

Segue a imagem como esta meu gridview[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: inclua o seu código

Comment: Seria bom você adicionar o código que usa para "alimentar" o _grid_. Em Windows Forms, a edição de dados de um grid sempre vai depender da fonte.

Answer (score 0):

gridItens.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 12);
            gridItens.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

```
        txtEAN.Focus();
        ITENS = new BindingList<ItemVendaView>();

        gridItens.DataSource = ITENS;
        AtualizaTotais();
```